# Get direct child within parrent

Tags: jquery

How to query div with `jquery` of class `ac` but inside `a` not `ab` ?

If i query `$('.a .ac')` it finds `ac` but inside `ab`

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="ab">
     <div> class="ac"></div>
  </div>
  <div> class="ac"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select an *immediate* child element with [the child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), for example:

```js
$('.a > .ac').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="ab">
     <div class="ac">inside ab</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ac">not inside ab</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [child-combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>`:

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It
> matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are
> the direct children of elements matched by the first.

```js
console.log($('.a > .ac'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="ab">
     <div class="ac"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ac"></div>
</div>
```